# When the country's currency is falling, does it make sense for Central Bank to intervene beyond curbing Volatity?

Tags: international-trade, central-banking, foreign-exchange, balance-of-trade

Consider a country who have more imports than exports. If the country's currency is falling badly with reference to the dollar (and the dollar is the main trading currency for the said country), then does it make sense for the Central Bank of the country to intervene beyond a point by selling dollars for the country's currency in the forex market.

I can understand the Central Bank trading localcurrency/USD to control volatility & not let the currency rise or fall too soon. But does any intervention beyond that make sense?

For e.g. is it worth it for the Central Bank to sell a lot of USD to artificially strengthen the local currency against the USD. Will this really make imports cheaper? I am unable to figure out what is the cost of selling USD so that it can be compared against net money saved in import costs because of lower cost of dollar because of selling dollars. Also are there are other factors to be considered to understand this?